# Particular solution error

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to solve for a particular solution (when $y = -1$ and $x = 1$) but seem to be stuck on the general solution.

```
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 1 - 2x - 3x^2$$
```

My initial answer was: $$y = x - x^2 - x^3 + C$$ , but the correct answer in my textbook is:$$ y=x - x^2 + 3x^{-1} + 4$$

Thanks :)

EDIT: Realised there was a typo in the question (Question 2b)! Thanks for your help everyone
[image]

Comment: You might like to fix typos using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) and include your working. You have two equal signs in the first maths expression.

Answer (score 3):

The answer in the textbook corresponds to $\frac{dy}{dx} = 1-2x-3x^{-2}$. My guess is that somewhere there is a typo, but whether that's in the original problem in your book, or in the solution (or in the author's notes when he made the solution), or in your notes from writing down the problem for the first time, I cannot tell.

When you're solving differential equations, it's usually a good idea to *check your solution*. It's often a lot less work than solving the equation, and it is a great help in spotting mistakes. And if you check your solution, and it works, then you most likely have the correct solution (the probability that the exact reverse of an error occurs when checking a solution is positive, but usually rather small).

Comment: Turns out there was a typo in the textbook, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your book solution answer a different question:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=1-2x-3x^{-2}$$

Your solution to the question that you posted seems fine. Just subtitute those particular value (when $x=1, y=-1$) to solve for $c$.

$$-1 = 1-2(1)-3(1^2)+c$$